# Java Paho MQTT client connection over reverse proxy

Tags: java, mqtt

I'm using the Java paho library to communicate to an mqtt broker. Using the code below I'm able to connect fine.

```
MqttClient publisher = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.1.100:1883","randomClientId");
MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
options.setCleanSession(true);
options.setConnectionTimeout(10);
publisher.connect(options);
```

However, I have the mqtt broker behind a reverse proxy, so I don't need to open up a separate port. So what I need to do is instead of connecting to "tcp://192.168.1.100:1883" I'd like to connect to "tcp://192.168.1.100/mqtt".
However, when I try this, I get an error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI path must be empty "tcp://13.251.5.125/mqtt"
```

I can do this just fine using libraries in python for example, but using the Java client I'm not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible to do with native MQTT.

The only way to get this to work is if you are using MQTT over Websockets. In which case you need to pass a URI that looks like:

`ws://192.168.1.100/mqtt`

Note it now starts with `ws://` not `tcp://`

Comment: the python implementation has added support for proxy:
https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L848

Can something like that be added for the java client too?

Comment: StackOverflow comments are not the right place to make feature requests to OS projects. I suggest you raise an issue on GitHub against the correct repo.

Comment: Also client access via a proxy is very different to the OPs question about putting the broker behind a reverse proxy.